# Adding user-defined field attibute WFFM

Tags: wffm, salesforce-connect

We are working on a form where the form data is sent to an external(SalesForce) API.
I have a custom Salesforce action which sends the post request with field data to SalesForce.

Now, to map fields with Salesforce Excel, Salesforce has provided with "Keys" to be used with each input Field.

E.g.

Sales force accepts first_name and last_name as keys.

Postdata will be `first_name=john&last_name=doe`.

How can I add a user-defined parameters to fields in WFFM fields?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ootb way to do this, and you probably don't want to create custom fields for every field type... What I did in a similar situation a while ago was creating the mapping outside of wffm - with a list of key/value pairs (this can be in a data section in Sitecore, or somewhere completely different). The key in this pair list is the field name (in the form) and the value the (Salesforce) key.

This way the form editors need to be aware of this map, so they can choose their field names correctly. That was not so easy in the beginning, but they learned.

We noticed that the list of field names / keys stayed rather small as it is mostly the same fields that are synced.

Comment: Thanks. 
This is workable approach. In my case, we have many check-boxes as well in the form, and check-boxes can have different titles. I believe it'll be too hard to add a key everytime.

Comment: Maybe you can define an algorithm to define the key (based on a prefix)?